# XXXXX doesn't Exist in current context ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've added some code to my MVC Controller to enable filtering. All is well apart from it's not recognising the DB table and the compiler tells me that the name 'bookingDate' does not exist in the current context but in the couple of lines above to pull the data from the DB it recognises it fine and Intellisense even suggested the autocomplete for it.

If I comment out the line it then gives me errors for the second ViewBag saying that one doesn't exist either! Below is the code for my controller. I'm using DB First Entity framework for my ORM. I removed the rest of the controller code to try to keep this short and sweet but I can post it if you need it.

BookingController:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using MooWoosCRM;

    namespace MooWoosCRM.Controllers
    {
public class BookingsController : Controller
{
    private Entities db = new Entities();

    // GET: Bookings
    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
    {
        ViewBag.bookingDate = (from r in db.bookings
                               select r.bookingDate).Distinct();
        ViewBag.stallType = (from r in db.bookings
                             select r.stallType).Distinct();
        var model = from r in db.bookings
                   where r.bookingDate == bookingDate || bookingDate == null || bookingDate == ""
                    where r.stallType == stallType || stallType == null || stallType == ""
                    select r;

        ViewBag.stallSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "stall_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
        var bookings = from s in db.bookings
                       select s;
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "stall_desc":
                bookings = bookings.OrderByDescending(s => s.stallType);
                break;
            case "Date":
                bookings = bookings.OrderBy(s => s.bookingDate);
                break;
            case "date_desc":
                bookings = bookings.OrderByDescending(s => s.bookingDate);
                break;
            default:
                bookings = bookings.OrderBy(s => s.bookingTime);
                break;
        }
        return View(db.bookings.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Bookings/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        booking booking = db.bookings.Find(id);
        if (booking == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(booking);
    }
```

Comment: You have not declared a variable named `bookingDate`. You just assigned it to a `ViewBag` property. It would need to be `where r.bookingDate == ViewBag.bookingDate` etc

Comment: And `return View(db.bookings.ToList());` makes a mockery of all the code above - its just returning all bookings unordered. I assume it should be `return View(bookings.ToList());`

Comment: But `ViewBag.bookingDate` is `IEnumerable<T>` so the `.Where()` clause would not work anyway. Not really clear what you wanting to do. `bookingdate` needs to be a single value of you need to be using a `Contains()`

Comment: I've just noticed that in the ActionResult needed them set as strings as below: public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string bookingDate, string stallType)

Comment: `bookingDate` sounds like a `DateTime` so it should be `DateTime bookingDate` or `DateTime? bookingDate` (not `string`)